# Is there a r function to fill factor value based on another factor value

Tags: r, for-loop, time, factors

Need output:(Unit_New based on Unit and ID)

```
> x
       CD   ID   Unit  Unit_New
1       1   222   EM       EM
2       2   222   EM       EM
3       3   555  NAM      NAM
4       4   555  NAM      NAM
5       5   555   GT      NAM
6       6   777   GT       EM
7       7   777   EM       EM
8       8   999   EM       EM
9       9   999   AO       EM
10     10   111   AO       AO
```

Comment: groub by (ID) and fill all Unit_New one value from Unit

Comment: use Unit_List = c("EM", "NAM", "AO")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could make use of the 'Unit_List' to create a `factor` with `levels` based on that `list`, then select the `first` `level` after dropping the unused `levels`, grouped by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
Unit_List = c("EM", "NAM", "AO")
x %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Unit_New1 = levels(droplevels(factor(Unit, levels = Unit_List)))[1])
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   ID [5]
#      CD    ID Unit  Unit_New Unit_New1
#   <int> <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr>    
# 1     1   222 EM    EM       EM       
# 2     2   222 EM    EM       EM       
# 3     3   555 NAM   NAM      NAM      
# 4     4   555 NAM   NAM      NAM      
# 5     5   555 GT    NAM      NAM      
# 6     6   777 GT    EM       EM       
# 7     7   777 EM    EM       EM       
# 8     8   999 EM    EM       EM       
# 9     9   999 AO    EM       EM       
#10    10   111 AO    AO       AO
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(CD = 1:10, ID = c(222L, 222L, 555L, 555L, 555L, 
777L, 777L, 999L, 999L, 111L), Unit = c("EM", "EM", "NAM", "NAM", 
"GT", "GT", "EM", "EM", "AO", "AO"), Unit_New = c("EM", "EM", 
"NAM", "NAM", "NAM", "EM", "EM", "EM", "EM", "AO")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```